# Can I find lost phone with power off? How to take back data from lost phone?

Tags: lost-phone

1. My Asus Zenfone5 lost 2 dsys ago, I can't find it beacuse its power off. So I was wondering if there is any software I can turn it on without installed any apps on it before. If not i can only buy a new one.
2. I know I can redownload apps by google, but I can't find my photos in google+. I'm not sure did I backup or sync them to somewhere else and don't know how to find it. Is there any way I can find out?

Comment: 1) Afraid you need to buy a new one. Chances to find it are little, unless you know where you lost it or it's a narrow area. No "remote power-on" – for on what should that react if it's not powered already? 2) If you didn't make backups, you'll have nothing to restore from, sorry. I don't use Google Apps for that (I always backup to my own computers, not to "other people's computers" aka Cloud), so I cannot tell you where to look; but I'd start with Google Drive, which is where most of those backups go to.

Comment: 1) As Izzy said, you are out of luck, 2) Login to the same Google account you had on your phone and go to https://photos.google.com for your picture and video backups to see if they exist. You can also go to https://myaccount.google.com/dashboard and open the Android tile and if there is a Backup, click that link which will take you to the Google Drive file, double clicking that will tell you (vaguely) what it contains, typically call history, apps (and their configuration settings, not the actual data), and system settings like wallpaper and WiFi passwords. If it's not there, it's gone.

Comment: Thanks for suggests. So if I can't find my picture in Google photo that means I didn't Backup and can not find it in dashboard's Backup right? I stored some of them in SD card on that phone.